# berkeleydbje to set authentication

Tags: security, authentication, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

How to set the user authentication on my database application in berkeley db java edition.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw that this question had gone unanswered. The short answer is that Berkeley DB is an embedded database. It links into your application. There is no concept of user identity or authentication within the BDB library. Authenticating and managing access to the data is a function of the embedding application. In other words, your application should authenticate the user using whatever mechanism works best for you.

In the future you may find that you get faster answers about Berkeley DB products on the Oracle Technology Network forums for Berkeley DB, which can be found [here](http://bit.ly/e5KwzV).